# How can the "Bar Holder with Clip" part be used?

Tags: building, piece-usage

I'm wondering whether the "bar holder" end of this element (http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=11090) can be used as a stud. In other words, would it have enough clutch power to hold e.g. a 1x1 plate? And what about a 1x1 brick?

The reason for asking this question is that I'm looking for an element with a clip on one side and a stud on the other side. Sort of like this element (http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=2555) but with a stud at the bottom. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

One [possible solution](https://www.flickr.com/photos/62bricks/14156666274) might be to use one of the new [1x1 round plates with open studs](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=85861) and a [Bar with Clip](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=48729)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that 1x1 plate element crossed my mind but I didn't see what part to connect it to. However, does this mean that the end of the `Bar Holder with Clip` can't be used as stud?

Comment: @Ailurus - Indeed - I think think the "Bar Holder" part of the description implies you can only insert a Bar into it :(

Comment: I tried connecting the Bar Holder with Clip to a brick and a plate, and it is too large to be used as a stud. Obviously, you can stick a bar into it (like Zhaph said).